Power loss in transformer windings
I am having a confusion while designing the transformer for my smps design. I am in the initial stage of setting my equations for the transformer. I have been following the slides from the Fundamentals of Power electronics by Robert Erickson.
There I found the equations of proximity effect where they used it to find the wire diameter. I am abit confused regarding the equation as how they have normalized the equation given below:


A graph of this is drawn for each layer and then a normalized graph is drawn. I am not getting how this normalized graph is formed. From slides page 897.


The Pdc equation shown should be equal to M*I^R and it doesnt depend on phi so Pdc at phi=1 will be the same equation. and dividing it should give me the equaion shown below:

But in the text I am getting the following result...

Kindly help me how this normalization works.
Second question:
I wanted to find the wire guage for my smps so will I be finding it from the graph shown above or I have to use these equations shown below on page 965 of slides. Here there is no consideration of frequency done.

Finally in making the normalization do I always have to do it with phi=1? and choose my diameter.
I think Ive asked alot in but kindly help me get around these things so I might move forward.
